# QWidget reports wrong width value

Tags: qt, qwidget

I want to query a widget's width to carry out some custom layout management. Unfortunately, the following code returns 640 no matter how big or small the widget actually is

```
int myWidth = this->rect().size().width();  // "this" is my class derived from QWidget
// myWidth is set to 640
```

EDIT:

`int myWidth = this->width()` returns the same 640

Comment: Why not just `int myWidth = this->width();`

Comment: Are you calling this function before or after your widget has been shown?

Comment: Have you tried calling `sizeHint` or `adjustSize` on your widget?

Comment: @Chris I am calling this function before the widget has been shown. Is that the issue here?

Comment: @phyatt I don't want to implement `sizeHint` or `adjustSize` for this widget because I want it to expand for which I have called `setSizePolicy`. I just want the widget to expand to fit inside its parent and once it does so, I want to query its width

Comment: Thanks @Chris, calling the function after rendering gives me the correct width. I have currently implemented this using a singleshot timer in the constructor. But is there a way to know when exactly the widget gets rendered?

Comment: You shouldn't need to reimplement `sizeHint` or `adjustSize`.  If you call `sizeHint`, it can figure out some of the calculations for its rendered size, for when you ask for its `rect()->size()->width()`.  Calling `adjustSize` is another way to tell the widget to update its geometry for elements that have resized inside of it or elements that have been added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct place to do special layout management is overridden [`resizeEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent). At that point size of widget is decided (usually by parent widget's layout, based on [size hint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) and [size policy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop)). It's guaranteed to get called before widget is shown for the first time, too. Remember to call super class [`resizeEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) too, at least if you have child widgets in layout.